# How to include ejb project files in war

Tags: buildpath

i have created a ejb project in eclipse and a web project which includes the ejb project in build path. but after deploying the web project the ejb files are not being found. how to include the ejb files and web project.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create an `Enterprise Application Project` (in addition to your previously create ones). Select the Java EE module dependencies you need, in your case, the two projects `ejb` and `web`. When deployed, the artifact should contain all dependencies. If you need to export it, choose `Java EE > EAR file`.